# How to store data for a web forum android application?

Tags: android

I have investigated the possibility of shared preferences, and SQL Lite options for storing data, but these options only seem to be for storing data for one particular phone. I want to build an interactive web forum, which means keeping data from multiple users (comments, responses, topics, threads, user info). What are some options to store data for this type of applicaton?

I have thought about using Parse.com, but I do not know if Parse.com will work for a complex web forum application and the related data requirements...how do other applications store data over the network? What are some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

## Create WebServices & use it in your app

You can create a **web-service** call it from your mobile application all data will be available on your mobile at run-time either receive in **XML** or **JSon** or some other format.

On **web-service** use your database either **MS-SqlServer** or **MySql** or **Oracle** and several other choices are available use as per your requirement.

Note: you can call web-service from any device any time and all of them will be always updated